# Android incoming sms popup

Tags: android, sms

I want to match a String sms phone number (incoming sms) to a String Studentno (variable). How can i match and notify popup msg if successful. here's my code:

```
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) 
{
    // Get SMS map from Intent
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    String messages = "";
    String address = "";
    String studentsno = "+0999234678";
    String no;
    if ( extras != null )
    {
        // Get received SMS array
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( SMS_EXTRA_NAME );

        // Get ContentResolver object for pushing encrypted SMS to incoming folder
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i )
        {
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);

            String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
            address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

            messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";                    
            messages += body + "\n";

            no  = sms.getOriginatingAddress().toString();

            // Here you can add any your code to work with incoming SMS

            if(no  == studentsno){
                Toast.makeText( context, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }

            // I added encrypting of all received SMS 
            putSmsToDatabase( contentResolver, sms );
        }

        // Display SMS message
        Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
}
```

This is my problem. how can I match 2 Strings to display popup msg? :

```
if(no  == studentsno){
    Toast.makeText( context, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(no.equals(studentsno))
```

instead of

```
if(no == studentsno)
```

EDIT: Long story short, **String.equals()** will compare if the values of the given strings are equal (this is what you need in your situation).

**==** will check if the compare objects are referring to the exact same String object. So even if the comparing Strings have the same value, they are *not* referring to the same String object.

Comment: Please explain why, or the OP and future searchers learn nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all strings are objects.  When you use the `==` operator with objects, *you are testing whether two objects are the same object*.

Because of `string interning`, strings **might** be the same object but often not, and you are not able to influence this.

The Java `Object` class implements an equals method which simply tests if two objects are the same object.  Any class which inherits from `Object` may override this method to provide it's own equality test.  `string` does this by overriding the `equals` method to test whether two strings (the same object or different objects, it doesn't matter) contain the same *content*.

Therefore, when testing whether two strings have the *same content*, you should use `string1.equals(string2)`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning